# How to change quantity with php and plausible js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Okay so I have this problem on a site im working om.. some merchandise that have been selected are POST'ed from a form to this page. Then the prices are gathered from the db and it all gets added to get the total sum price.. However I need to get a function where you can change the quantity of the items selected.

The code I have so far is this - For displaying the selected products.

```html
$t_id=implode(',',$t_id);//impload the value with the ',' and used IN operate to get all the value relate this id  (11, 19 and 20)
$query = "SELECT * FROM tilbehor WHERE t_id IN ($t_id)";
$result = $db->query($query);
$num_rows = $result->num_rows;
 if($num_rows > 0) {
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "
   &#8729; <input type='text' style='width: 50px;' name='quantity' id='quantity' class='txt' value='1'> - <b>".$row['tilbehor_navn']."</b><br>
  ";
 }
} else {
echo "Error";
}
```

And here is the code to display and add up alle the prices.

```html
$test = $_POST['tilbehor'];
$test=implode(',',$test);//impload the value with the ',' and used IN operate to get all the value relate this id  (11, 19 and 20)
$query = "SELECT * FROM tilbehor WHERE t_id IN ($test)";
$result = $db->query($query);
$num_rows = $result->num_rows;
 if($num_rows > 0) {
  
$number = $p_pris + $o_tilbehor_pris;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $number += $row['kunde_pris'];
}

$output = $number;
$followers = number_format( $output , 0 , '.' , '.' );
echo "
<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='price' value='$followers'>Kunde pris $followers<br>
";


  
} else {
 $number = $p_pris + $o_tilbehor_pris;
 $output = $number;
 $followers = number_format( $output , 0 , '.' , '.' );
 echo $followers;
 echo ",-";
}
```

Anyone have any idea on how to code it so you can change the quantity of an item and so that the price is affected as well? :)

Comment: Please work on your coding, it's very messy and hard to read. Also, I don't understand your question. What is it exactly that you need/miss? If you need to update the products, you will have to make an ajax call and update the quantity with that..

Comment: Provide an input field for the quantity (probably using `type=number`), so the user can change it – and then submit the form again, so that the new price can be calculated. If you want to do it “instantly” without the user submitting the form again, use JavaScript – either an AJAX request that submits the data in the background, or calculate the new price client-side (for that you’d need the price per piece accessible client-side as well, f.e. in a custom data attribute).